# ValidationError: ObjectId not getting pushed into the array.. Resulting a ValidationError

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to backend web development, learning **Data Associations** at the moment... I got an error which seems severe to me since I'm a newbie in this topic...I'm trying to add up the **ObjectId** of **Post** in **postArray** of my **userSchema**.

When I add the first post to a particular user, I'm not getting what I expected.. I was expecting to get the **ObjectId** pushed into the **postArray** but the actual thing happened here was the entire **newPost** got pushed into the **postArray**.This is the first problem encountered. And I get no errors here, but I didn't get what I expected!

The second one is when I add another post to **postArray**, It gives me a huge error naming **ValidationError**.. I literally spent hours trying to fix this error which may be a minor one but a pain for me. My code is given below and the error is also posted below!

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/testdatabase");

var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: String,
   content: String
});

var Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

var userSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    postArray: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post'
    }]
});
var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

var alex = new User({
    name: "Alexander",
    email: "alexander@gmail.com"
});

alex.save();

Post.create({
    title: "I'm terribly stuck here!",
    content: "Does anyone have an idea of where I'm stuck?"
}, function(err, newPost) {
    User.findOne({name: "Alexander"}, function(err, foundUser) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("THE NEWLY ADDED POST IS" + newPost);
            foundUser.postArray.push(newPost);
            foundUser.save(function(err, savedData) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(savedData);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

> `Blackdeath:~/environment/Associations $ node references.js
>   THE NEWLY ADDED POST IS{ _id: 5a5845c180a490137330bcae,
>     title: 'I\'m terribly stuck here!',
>     content: 'Does anyone have an idea of where I\'m stuck?',
>     __v: 0 }
>   { ValidationError: User validation failed: postArray: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[{"_id":"5a5844112d4c6512beb16846","title":"This makes me sick!","content":"I\'m stuck here..Someone save me!","__v":0}]" at path "postArray"
>       at MongooseError.ValidationError (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:27:11)
>       at model.Document.invalidate (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1643:32)
>       at _init (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:413:18)
>       at init (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:381:5)
>       at model.Document.$__init (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:351:3)
>       at model.syncWrapper [as $__init] (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/kareem/index.js:234:23)
>       at model.Document.init (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:319:8)
>       at completeOne (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1980:12)
>       at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1502:11)
>       at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:119:16)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
>     errors: 
>      { postArray: 
>         { ValidatorError: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[{"_id":"5a5844112d4c6512beb16846","title":"This makes me sick!","content":"I\'m stuck here..Someone save me!","__v":0}]" at path "postArray"
>             at MongooseError.ValidatorError (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validator.js:25:11)
>             at _init (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:413:37)
>             at init (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:381:5)
>             at model.Document.$__init (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:351:3)
>             at model.syncWrapper [as $__init] (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/kareem/index.js:234:23)
>             at model.Document.init (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:319:8)
>             at completeOne (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1980:12)
>             at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1502:11)
>             at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/environment/Associations/node_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:119:16)
>             at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
>             at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
>             at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
>           message: 'Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[{"_id":"5a5844112d4c6512beb16846","title":"This makes me sick!","content":"I\\\'m stuck here..Someone save me!","__v":0}]" at path "postArray"',
>           name: 'ValidatorError',
>           properties: [Object],
>           kind: 'cast',
>           path: 'postArray',
>           value: '[{"_id":"5a5844112d4c6512beb16846","title":"This makes me sick!","content":"I\'m stuck here..Someone save me!","__v":0}]',
>           reason: undefined } },
>     _message: 'User validation failed',
>     name: 'ValidationError' }`

Comment: Question must be specific to understand, don't simply paste raising error to title, which makes the question vague to understand but to elaborate inside question body will be useful for others to understand and the answer providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. I failed to add the mongoose package to package.json

At first, I just did

```
npm install mongoose
```

Later I tried doing

```
npm install mongoose --save
```

And it worked!